# Pulling friends birthdays through facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been working on trying to pull friends birthdays from the facebook API and I have been able to pull my friends uid's but when I replace the uid request with anything else (i.e, name,sex,birthday, etc.) it breaks the code.  Any insight would be a major help. Thanks

```
 <div id="fb_login"> 

             <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId      : 'APP_ID',
                status     : true, 
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true,
              });
            };
            (function(d){
               var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
               js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
               js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
               d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
             }(document));
          </script>
        <div class="fb-login-button" scope="user_birthday,friends_birthday">Login with Facebook</div>



      <div id="bday_display">
      <?php
                $app_id = 'APP_ID';
                $app_secret = 'APP_SECERT';
                $my_url = 'MY_URL';


                $code = $_REQUEST["code"];



               //auth user
               if(empty($code)) {
                  $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
                  . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
                  echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
                }

                //get user access_token
                $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
                  . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
                  . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
                  . '&code=' . $code;
                $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

                // Run fql query
                $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
                  . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
                  . '&' . $access_token;
                $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
                $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);



                //display results of fql query
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r("query results:");
                print_r($fql_query_obj);
                echo '</pre>';





              ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked.  Thanks for all your help cpilko.  I couldn't have got it done with out your help.

```
        try{
            $fql    =   "SELECT name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2          FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())";
            $param  =   array(
                 'method'    => 'fql.query',
                'query'     => $fql,
                'callback'  => ''
            );
            $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
        }
        catch(Exception $o){
            d($o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fql statement. Keep in mind, not everyone will have populated their birthday field, or if they have, made it visible to you.

```
SELECT name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() )
```

You could add `AND strlen(birthday_date) > 0` to the end of the above FQL to filter out the friends who don't have a visible birthday.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't help.  This is super frustrating.  I do have to make this request from the user table though, correct?  It seems that I can pull data about my self as a user but as soon as I try to get my friends information it does nothing.  I have checked my permissions is my app and the all have been set.

Comment: Have you tried making the query from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) as your app to see if anything is getting returned? And yes, the `birthday_date` information is only in the `user` table.

Comment: I just tried your query in the explorer and it worked, however it did not return anything on my actual site.

Comment: Add `print_r($fql_query_result);` to your page and see what kind of errors this might be throwing. Also, is there any reason why you're not using the [php sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) to make this query?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do anything.  I have been trying to make this work for a week now and I suppose frustration is getting to me.  I am doing this on wordpress and I cant get this to work.  This was the only type of code that I came close with.  do you think that there is anything in wordpress that is impeding this?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: It is very possible. Look at the source of your pages. Lots of WP plugins add FB data into the head of your page. It's possible there is another appid another plugin is inserting into your `<head>` that's messing with your query causing oAuth mismatch. You might want to just try creating a php page outside of WP and seeing if your code works. Then you'll know if its you or WP.